# Using Listview to show posts in Tab layout

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

i'm using Listview on Tab Layout in my android app to load data from network. Tha tabs are working properly and i can switch between my tabs easily without any error but when the listview is populated with data from server the tabs go away and i've a simple listview with data. I can't see my other tabs anymore.
PS The data is loading just fine without any problem.

Here is the Home java code for home_layout

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home_layout);

    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

    TabHost.TabSpec myprofiletab = tabHost.newTabSpec("Profile");
    myprofiletab.setIndicator("Profile",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.myprofile_icon));
    Intent myprofileintent = new Intent(this,MyProfile.class);
    myprofiletab.setContent(myprofileintent);

    TabHost.TabSpec newsfeedtab = tabHost.newTabSpec("NewsFeed");
    newsfeedtab.setIndicator("Feed",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.newsfeed_icon));
    Intent feed = new Intent(this,NewsFeed.class);
    newsfeedtab.setContent(feed);

    tabHost.addTab(newsfeedtab);
    tabHost.addTab(myprofiletab);
}
```

Here is the home_layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem by adding one line to my FrameLayout

```
        <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@android:id/tabs" />
```